# switchMap, startWith, switchMap?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

```
this.timeline$ = app.selectedSites$.pipe(
  debounceTime(2000),
  switchMap(sites => this.interval.pipe(map(() => sites))),
  switchMap(sites =>
    analytics.timeline(sites, 60 * 24 * 2, 60).pipe(
      map(result => {
        const colors = getColors(result);

        return {
          labels: result[0].datapoints.map(pair => pair[1]),
          datasets: (<any[]>result).map((target, i) => ({
            pointRadius: 0,
            label: target.target,
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: colors[i % colors.length],
            borderColor: colors[i % colors.length],
            data: target.datapoints.map(pair => ({
              y: pair[0],
              x: pair[1]
            }))
          }))
        };
      })
    )
  ),
  share()
);
```

I'd like this.timeline$ to emit `null` when selectedSites$ changes (debounced) and it starts loading the first data for the new list, then also refresh every 30 seconds but not emit null before refreshing... I can't figure out where to put the startWith(null) in here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In another word - you want two streams: first with all operators, and another that emit `null`.

```
const source$ = app.selectedSites$
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(2000)
  )


this.timeline$ = source$.pipe(
  switchMap(sites => this.interval.pipe(map(() => sites))),
  switchMap(sites =>
    analytics.timeline(sites, 60 * 24 * 2, 60)
      .pipe(
        map(result => getField(result))
      )
  ),
  merge(source$.pipe(mapTo(null))),
  share()
);
```

Comment: your answer does seem to work so I'm accepting your answer... I ended up with a slightly different solution though.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with...

```
toChartData(selector: (sites: string[]) => Observable<any>) {
    return this.app.selectedSites$.pipe(
      debounceTime(2000),
      switchMap(sites =>
        this.interval.pipe(
          switchMap(() => selector(sites)),
          startWith(null)
        )
      ),
      share()
    );
}
```